# Keyboard layout keeps allways falling back to default after reboot - how to change?

Tags: keyboard, reboot, language-support, locale, layout

I have Chromebook Acer C7 and i like it. It's fast etc. 
To install *buntu linux on it i did use Crouton. It's a program who install *buntu on ChromeOS without erace the orginal system.

Anyway! 
I have problem with the keyboard layout. I have Swedish keyboard but the keyboard layout in the system is US keyboard.

I can install Swedish keyboard layout by using this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

After that, i have Swedish keyboard layout. But after i reboot i falling back the the US keyboard layout.

```
(precise)acer@localhost:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "sv_SV.UTF-8",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "sv_SV.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "sv_SV.UTF-8",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "sv_SV.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "sv_SV.UTF-8",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "sv_SV.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
(precise)acer@localhost:~$
```

Here is /etc/default/keyboard

```
(precise)acer@localhost:~$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL=""
XKBLAYOUT="se"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
(precise)acer@localhost:~$
```

Here is /etc/default/locale

```
(precise)acer@localhost:~$ cat /etc/default/locale  
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="sv_SV.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="sv_SV.UTF-8"
(precise)acer@localhost:~$
```

Best Regards
Acer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old post but here is the solution I use on 16.04 (Xenial)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I'm also on 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal
2. Login with root `su`
3. Enter password of root
4. Update and Upgrade all with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. Type the following:

   ```
   apt-get install console-data
   apt-get install console-setup
   apt-get install console-locales
   apt-get install keyboard-configuration
   ```
6. Reboot and recheck.
7. Enjoy ;)

Comment: One should not interactively log into the root account, which is disabled on Ubuntu by default, so `su` will not work anyway. Use `sudo` for every command you would have ran as root instead! Besides that, being logged in as root *and* using `sudo` at the same time makes no sense.